# Firefox profile setting for auto download of jnlp file in unix

Tags: python, unix, firefox

i have tried like below in .py file but didn't work.Can you help me to resolve? 
My firefox version is **firefox-65.0.1**.

```
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml;application/x-java-jnlp-file")

firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_profile.add_extension()
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/root/Downloads/")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-java-jnlp-file")
    firefox_profile.update_preferences()
```

Comment: Give more details about why it does not work (no files are downloaded, you get an error message etc.)? Does saving other types of files work?

Comment: I am getting the following error message **The last error was: File '/root/tmp/start.jnlp' does not exist.** Can you correct it if my code is wrong?

Comment: still it sshowing the popup of open with & save file ..